# Determinant of a matrix operator.

Tags: linear-algebra

Take a field $\mathbb{F}$ and the space of all matrix $V$ on the field $\mathbb{F}$. $B$ is a fixed matrix of $V$. Define the three following operators on $V$.

1. $L_B(A) = BA$
2. $R_B(A) = AB$
3. $T_B(A) = BA - AB$

I like to find the determinant of these three operators. For first two operators answer is $\{\det(B)\}^n$ and for the third one it is $0$.

What I have done is the following.

Any matrix $A_{n \times n} = (a_{ij})$of $V$ can be expressed as a sum like
$$A = a_{11}E_{11} + a_{12}E_{12} + \dots + a_{nn}E_{nn},$$
Where $\{E_{11}, E_{12}, \dots, E_{nn}\}$ is an ordered basis of $V$. $E_{ij}$ is the matrix having $1$ at $(i,j)$-th position and all remains terms are $0$.

Now I have tried to find the corresponding matrices of $L_B, R_B$ and $T_B$. They all are matrices of order $n^2 \times n^2$. Then I am trying to find the determinants, but it is difficult, as all the matrices have  contain a large number of $0$s and elements of $B$ are coming in a peculiar manner.

If any other method is available, please suggest or help me to complete it in my process.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M=End(V)=M_n(F)$ be the matrix algebra. Then the left multiplication operator in $M$ is given by $L(B)A=BA$, the right multiplication operator by
$R(B)A=AB$ and the adjoint operator is $ad(B)(A)=[B,A]=BA-AB$. All these are endomorphisms of $M$, with the following determinants: since $ad(B)B=0$, $\det ad(B)=0$ for all $B$. 
For $\det L(B)=\det(B)^n$ etc. see [Finding trace and determinant of linear operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/339263/finding-trace-and-determinant-of-linear-operator), which answers the question.

Comment: Thank you. I have seen your link. I should approach some more steps.